# How do I clean up my machine after completing an OpenStack training course?

Tags: juju, openstack

I received the Ubuntu newsletter "
Lunch & Learn with OpenStack Containers".  I decided to give the installation a go.  Since then my Linux computer has been extremely slow taking up to 15 minutes for me to be able to log in.  This happens on every startup and shutdown.

Sometimes the OS comes up with error messages telling me that an internal error has occurred and would I like to report the error, to which I select the option to report the error.

When starting up and shutting down, it sounds like the HDD is being accessed continuously.  It sounds similar to as if the OS is doing a chkdsk/defrag (to use windows terminology).

Please tell me how to "reverse" the exercise?  I do not have a CDROM drive on the computer so can't run a repair from the CDROM.

Answer (score 3):

You may have a set of containers running in the background.

Try `lxc list` and if there are containers there that are not containers you specifically want to keep, then you can stop and remove them with:

```
lxc stop <name>
lxc delete <name>
```

Those containers are pretty lightweight, much more lightweight than VMs, you can run lots of them on a laptop which is nice for development of complex software like openstack. But they do add overhead especially if they are all booting when your laptop boots. Let us know if this helped.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Were all these containers added by that exercize and is it safe to remove them

Comment: Thanks. There were a number of juju containers added. Is it safe to remove them: wayne@WebServer:~$ lxc list
juju-52a913-0  | RUNNING | 10.33.150.24 (eth0)  |      | PERSISTENT | 0          juju-52a913-1  | RUNNING | 10.33.150.206 (eth0) |      | PERSISTENT | 0         
juju-52a913-10 | RUNNING | 10.33.150.43 (eth0)  |      | PERSISTENT | 0          juju-52a913-11 | RUNNING | 10.33.150.242 (eth0) |      | PERSISTENT | 0          juju-52a913-12 | RUNNING | 10.33.150.27 (eth0)  |      | PERSISTENT | 0         
etc ...